# Connect two Windows 10 computers with straight-through ethernet cable

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet

How can I connect two Windows 10 computers with straight-through ethernet cable? I don't have a crossover cable. [This post here](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-use-a-straight-through-cable-to-connect-two-computers/answer/Drazen-Zoric) gives me some chance that it is possible:

> Ethernet - using simple Ethernet cable. Most Ethernet adaptors today
> support proper switching eliminating need for cross-over cables.

But how? How can I "switch" to the use of straight-through cable?

Comment: Just plug both ends in. If it doesn't work, then at least one of the interfaces lacks the proper sensing. The only other thing to remember, is you probably have to give both systems a static IP address in the same subnet.

Comment: @Bib, thanks! So you're saying that it will go either automatically or not at all? There's no way to manually switch between crossover/straight-through?

Comment: No, no manual switch.

Comment: At most, the only thing you might be able to switch is the entire "auto-crossover" feature on/off -- but on Gigabit Ethernet interfaces, I don't think it's even possible to turn it off anyway. (The last time I skimmed through the standard, it seems like adapting to any possible pair mixups was a core part of the specification.)

Answer (score 5):

Since several years ago, all (or almost all) manufactured network adapters
work with both types of cables, straight or cross-over.

Unless your network adapter is old, there is an excellent chance that
any network cable will work for you.